# How to put a div to the right of .container in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically, I need to put a *back-to-top* button at the right side of the footer.

Something like this:
[image: what I need]

What I get is this:
[image: what I get]

You can see that there is a blank space between *footer* and the end of viewport, that space is the height the *back-to-top* button, if I remove the button the blank space is removed too.

I'm using bootstrap so my html code is similar to:

```
<footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content1>CONTENT 1</div>
        <div class="content2>CONTENT 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="back-to-top>TOP</div>
</footer>
```

You can see an example in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/hNuXYYWW2o). You can see that the footer has to be 20px height (`min-height: 20px`) but instead it is `40px`.

I think that my problem will be solved if I can put the `.back-to-top div` beside the `.container div`.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use helper class pull-right and move TOP link before container:

```
<footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="back-to-top pull-right">TOP</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content1>CONTENT 1</div>
        <div class="content2>CONTENT 2</div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

You need to remove your CSS bloc:

```
.back-to-top {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}
```

Doc: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats

Answer (score 0):

Having a `min-height` proxy doesn't mean you footer is going to be `20px`. That just mean its height won't be smaller than that. If you want your height to be 20px, use `height` property. If for some reason you want it to be variable, you can look to the `max-height` property.

For your "back-to-top" button, here is my suggestion :

http://jsfiddle.net/Bladepianist/38ne021p/

**HTML**

```
<footer class="container-fluid navbar-inverse">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">CONTENT 1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">CONTENT 2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-right" id="back-to-top">TOP</div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-fluid {
    color: white;
}
```

Basically, I change your "back-tot-top" class to an ID in my model but you're free to adapt it to your liking.
Using the col-system and the text-positions classes, you can achieve the same rendering as you show in your question. That way, the `back-to-top` button is part of the footer.

Hope that's helping ;).